# UV auto update not working

Tags: texturing, uv

I created my UV texture file and it is displaying fine in the UV/Image Editor window, but it is not showing up on the model.

In every tutorial and every where I've checked on the web it is supposed to auto update on the model and there is even an "Update Automatically" check box, which is ticked, but not working.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Ignore the properties window, adding it as a texture should only be necessary for final renders, to my understanding.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I discovered my fault. 
the auto update texture only works while selecting your model on the EDIT MODE of the 3d View window, then selecting the desired texture on the UV/Image Editor window.
i was selecting the texture without entering edit mode. :9

Comment: please add more to this answer. If this solved your problem, I still do not know what you did differently. If you add more to your answer it will be able to help future viewers.